# displaying ads on a Android TV app using Google PAL SDK

Tags: java, android, android-tv, vast

I am currently working on building an Android TV app for testing purposes. This app will play video ads using a vast tag and will also be integrated with the Google PAL SDK. Since I primarily work as a Roku Brightscript developer, I don't have much experience with Android TV development. Therefore, I was wondering if any of you could kindly assist me with the process. If you have any tips or sample code that you could share, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you in advance for your help!